# Sorting Relation_Aggregation Expression Results in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, expression, relationship-class

I am using a relation aggregation expression to grab a list of inflows from other sewersheds. Some sewersheds take on flows from more sewersheds than others so I approached it through a relation so that I can show all the values from both the Gravity In Flows and the In Flows from other sewersheds. It works but it presents the results in no particular order it seems. Is there something I can add to the expression that will sort the results by the Network Number?

```
CASE WHEN round((relation_aggregate('Network_Groups','sum',"Network_Consumption     Sheet1_None")),2) IS NOT NULL THEN
'Network '|| "networkGrp" ||'\n   Gravity In Flows '|| round("GFlow",2) ||'     m'||char(179)
||'\n   Liftstation In Flows'||
'\n     '||relation_aggregate('Network_Groups','concatenate', 'Network     '||"In_Network"||' '||"Network_Consumption Sheet1_None"||' m'||char(179),     concatenator:='\n     ')||char(179)||'\n  Total From Liftstations     '||round((relation_aggregate('Network_Groups','sum',"Network_Consumption Sheet1_None")),2)||' m'||char(179)
||'\n  Absolute Total 
'||round((relation_aggregate('Network_Groups','sum',"Network_Consumption 
Sheet1_None")+ "GFlow"),2) ||' m'||char(179)
ELSE 'Network '|| "networkGrp" ||'\n   Gravity In Flow '|| round("GFlow",2) ||'     
m'||char(179) END
```

Comment: I found that if I sort the table in LibreOffice Calc and reload it that the returns sort by the same function. I would still like to find a way to do it from within the expression.